# ANDROID - How to debug system services on Android using GDB

Tags: android, linux, debugging, exploit

I m interested in security stuff and I want to start with Android device to test this OS. I ve seen that there are many exploit for Android (the most famous is the stagefright case) and I m also curious to start developing something like that. I know how memory works and I' ve much experience in Linux exploitation techniques (Both buffer and Heap stuff).

Of course I' ve some questions about Android basics and tools:

1) I' ve already downloaded the AOSP so I can read the SourceCode without problem. So the Static analysis can be done easily and I don't need something like IDA or BinaryNinja like in Linux to analyze code.
   -But what about dynamic analysis/debug systems? 
In linux I use GDB to check The Heap Layout or Buffer status or      Register conditions and so on.. 
   -But how can I debug system stuff using GDB?

2) I' ve seen that Stagefright exploit affected the Mpeg4Extractor.cpp snippets that is in the Stagefright folder (from which the name of exploit of course). 
   - But I' m wonder how they verify the heap status or registers during    the exploitation? 
   - Did they use some debugger for Android? 
   - And how they debugged that specific snippet of code (Mpeg4Extractor.cpp)?

3) Do you suggest some tutorials: videos, papers or write-ups to begin to set up tools and learn how to debug SYSTEM .c or .cpp files?

Comment: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/wiki/Android-debugging-with-remote-GDB . This can be useful.But I'm curious to know the answer of all that questions too.

Comment: Thanks.. I hope someone will responde.. Probably the questions are too hard.

Comment: Code which you see might differ from what you have on a device (with exception of pure vanila devices like nexus). Debugging is the same as in linux remote debugging - the only important problem is that due to wtachdogs some processes will crash after short time (I will look for workaround  if you need). Other stuff related to analyzis (heap, stack, registers) does not differ from unix - as well as ld preloading (here is limit to preloding libraries per process, or at least was). Some CVEs has implemeted POC apps some are theroretical but whatever is used in gdb on  linux is valid here.